# Multidimensional Arrays JavaScript Challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a challenge on a website, as follows:

> Complete the function createToDoList, so that the returned multidimensional array contains at least three tasks listed as nested arrays.

> Step 1: Create the task sub-arrays.

> The first element of each nested array should be a string describing the task.
> The second element should be a number representing how long that task will take in minutes.

> Step 2: Add the arrays to the toDoList.

> Select an appropriate array method that will allow you to add to toDoList.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function createToDoList() {
    const toDoList = [];
    // Do not alter any code above here
    const tasks = [
        ['task 1', 45],
        ['task 2', 87],
        ['task 3', 83]
    ];

    toDoList.push(tasks);
    // Do not alter any code below here
    return toDoList;
}
```

Clearly I'm not understanding something here, I don't know how to push the arrays into the variable (if that's what it is asking me...), I really just don't get it.

Thanks.

Comment: You are pushing the whole nested array into the todolist as a single object. Either do `todolist.push(...tasks)` or get rid of your tasks variable and do `todolist.push(['task1', 45]); ...` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have what you want in `tasks` so you could just return that. As you're not allowed to change the some parts of the code you can use the fact that an array is an [`Iterable`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_iterables.asp) and use the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to push all the elements in `tasks` into `toDoList`.

```js
function createToDoList() {
    const toDoList = [];
    // Do not alter any code above here
    const tasks = [
        ['task 1', 45],
        ['task 2', 87],
        ['task 3', 83]
    ];

    toDoList.push(...tasks);
    // Do not alter any code below here
    return toDoList;
}

console.log(createToDoList())
```

You could also use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
function createToDoList() {
    const toDoList = [];
    // Do not alter any code above here
    const tasks = [
        ['task 1', 45],
        ['task 2', 87],
        ['task 3', 83]
    ];

    tasks.forEach(task => toDoList.push(task));
    // Do not alter any code below here
    return toDoList;
}

console.log(createToDoList())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the spread operator did the trick.